# What is the correct way to use multiple charAt's in a if else statement?

Tags: java, char

trying to check the user's input for the first and last two letters being a Letter datatype for a text-based game. I keep receiving a not a statement error. Not sure why any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner.*;

public class name info{

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Job Name:");
    String JobName = console.nextInt();

    if (isLetter(str.charAt(str.length-1))&&(isLetter(str.CharAt(1)){
      system.out.println ("Job name approved");
    }
    else {
     System.out.Println(JobName+" is not a valid job name.");
    }
    System.out.Println("part 1 End");
  }
}

error: ')' expected
error:not a statement
```

Comment: After your first condition, you either need a nested if statement, or you need an && or !!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you are using to check the conditions is incorrect.  However, I would strongly advise using a regex option with `String#matches` here:

```
String LastName = console.nextInt();
if (lastName.matches("(?i)(?!.* .* .* )[A-Z]{2}")) {
    System.out.println("Last name approved");
else {
    System.out.Println(LastName + " is not a valid last name.");
}
```

Comment: Maybe OP is new with java (see the mistakes) I think it's better to write some easy solution or fix those mistakes will be more helpful, IMHO ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

There are two problem in your code. First of all, you have to put an "if" before the line:

```
(isLetter(str.charAt(str.length-1))&&(isLetter(str.CharAt(1))
```

**So the code is:**

```
import java.util.Scanner.*;

public class EmploymentInfo{

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your last name:");
    String LastName = console.nextInt();

    if(LastName.indexOf(" ")<2){ //cond1
      if (isLetter(str.charAt(str.length-1))&&(isLetter(str.CharAt(1)){ //cond2
        //What to do if condition 1 & 2 are verified
      }else{
        //What to do if only cond 1 is verified
      }//end if cond2
    }else {
        //what if cond 1 is NOT verified
    }//end if cond1
    //other code
  }
}
```

Another problem is the use of **indexOf**. You want to check if the user input *not uses more than two spaces*, but indexOf *Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character* ([see Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html))

---

As suggested, here a method to find the number of spaces in your string:

```
public static int foundedSpaces(String s){
  char space = ' ';
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i) == space) {
          count++;
      }
  }
  return count;
}
```

You can can call `foundedSpaces(LastName)<2` instead of `LastName.indexOf(" ")<2`

Another problem is the use of java.util.Scanner.**nextInt()**: this method *scans the next token of the input as an int* ([see this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm)), but you want a string. Replace it with **nextLine()**.

Comment: How does this answer check that no more than two spaces are present?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question was "why I receiving a not a statement error?", not "How can I check if there are no more than two spaces"...

Comment: However I have updated my answer, as suggested, with a method that allows you to find the number of spaces and other useful tips for using the scanner.